# Measure of dense $G_\delta$ set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite regular Radon measure on $X$ which does not assign measure 0 to non-empty open subsets of $X$.

If $Y\subseteq X$ is a dense $G_\delta$ set the must it have positive $\mu$-measure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not even for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  Enumerate the rationals as $q_n$ and for each $\epsilon > 0$ let $U_\epsilon = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (q_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}, q_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n})$.  Clearly $U_\epsilon$ is open and dense, and its Lebesgue measure is at most $2\epsilon$.  Now consider $G = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty U_{1/k}$.  Then $G$ is $G^\delta$ and it still contains $\mathbb{Q}$, so it's dense, but its measure is less than that of any $U_{1/k}$, so it has measure zero.

A similar construction would work for a non-atomic Radon measure on any separable metric space.

Comment: Oh true...I was getting hopeful I think.  Thanks Nate :)

Comment: @AIM_BLB: The thing to remember is that there is no relationship between a set being large/small in the sense of Baire category, and being large/small in the sense of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Oh true.  I forgot about the Baire results...thanks for the very insightful answer....I'll need to find a new approach

Comment: A good reference for this kind of questions revolving around being small/large in the two senses mentioned by Nate is the beautiful short book "Measure and Category" by Oxtoby

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti The construction in the answer is in chapter 1 of that book IIRC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I just checked and you're right, it's part of the construction of two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ with $A$ meagre, $B$ of measure zero and $A\cup B=\Bbb R$

Comment: Thanks for this reference, I was not aware of it Alessandro

Comment: @Nate_Eldredge I'm curious, if I suppose that X is Banach and that Y contains a sense linear subspace, is there still nothing to be said? (Since in this case the counter example does not hold)

Comment: Typically you will be able to find a dense linear subspace $E$ of measure zero.  (For instance, if $\mu$ is Gaussian, the Cameron-Martin subspace is an example.)  Let $G$ be a dense $G^\delta$ of measure zero, constructed as above, and set $Y = E \cup G$.  If you want the subspace itself to be $G^\delta$, or even nonmeager, things are harder: at least when $X$ is separable, a nonmeager linear subspace cannot be Borel, and you need the axiom of choice to construct such a thing.